# Download attribute for downloading an HTML file of a div outputs an file with the HTML in one contiguous line.

Tags: html, download

I am using the HTML5 download attribute to download the HTML of a particular div:

```
var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
                        );
        a.download = "export.html";
        a.href = "data:text/attachment," + document.getElementById("export").innerHTML;
        a.innerHTML = "[Export content]";
```

This works but the HTML file comes out in one continuous line:

```
<tr><td><p>ADL</p></td><td><p>Some text here.</p></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><p>...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify that I am looking for the HTML to come out with proper indentation

Comment: Does the innerHTML have proper indentation?

Comment: It does, and when I logged it in the console it looked fine. I actaully figuerd it out though. I had to change the href to:  
`a.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(code);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing my href to the following:

`a.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(code);`